# get string from a string after a sub string.

Tags: javascript, replace

I want sub string **bo/log/classCount** from the string **//192.168.2.182/E$/My Tutorial/JSF/_TRAINING/bo/log/classCount** in java script, I have tried it using replace method but is it not working. Please help me.

```
I have tried 

var main = '//192.168.2.182/E$/My Tutorial/JSF/_TRAINING/bo/log/classCount';
var start = '//192.168.2.182/E$/My Tutorial/JSF/_TRAINING/';
var sub = main.replace(start, "");
```

Comment: That code works, but you could just as easily use `main.substr(start.length)`

Comment: How is it not working? What do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you have posted seems to work fine, but you can make it much cleaner using:

```
var main = '//192.168.2.182/E$/My Tutorial/JSF/_TRAINING/bo/log/classCount',
    start = '//192.168.2.182/E$/My Tutorial/JSF/_TRAINING/',
    sub = main.substr(start.length);
```

`sub` now contains `bo/log/classCount`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2uX/1/)